# Help me identify this spider from my garden

Tags: arachnology, species-identification

Found this in my garden today in Sydney, Australia (specifically Lane Cove). Can you tell me what it is?

[image: spider from above]
[image: spider from below]

Comment: Can you get a close up shot of the top?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is a [Garden Orb Weaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb-weaver_spider) spider. The Australian garden orb weaver, [Eriophora transmarina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_garden_orb_weaver_spider), has a strikingly similar body

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_garden_orb_weaver_spider#/media/File:Eriophora_transmarina.jpg]

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_garden_orb_weaver_spider#/media/File:Orb_weaver_black_bckgrnd03_crop.jpg]

Comment: Haha, yours is WAY closer than mine! You have to cut me a break though, this is my first attempted species-identification. Perhaps I should delete my answer to spare myself the humiliation... all the same, great job. +1

Comment: @CDB thanks. Species identification can be difficult but it is fun to play detective.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Neoscona Crucifera to me, but I could be wrong.

Here is a picture of her:

[image]

Another one, only this is more of the web:

[image]

Comment: wrong continent for *Neoscona crucifera*, which is found in the US and Mexico.